# Getting geth to become public RPC node?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I created an ETH light node with geth and it works great on my local server. The problem is that it's not visible to the public and I want it to be available for anyone to access. How do I do this with geth, it's driving me nuts!

My geth config if it helps:

`geth --syncmode "light" --http --ws --http.api "eth,net,web3" --http.corsdomain "*" --http.addr "0.0.0.0"`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with "not visible to the public"? Why do you want to make it public? If you left some port open in a public server you will get a lot of request from bots.

Comment: Open to the public meaning anyone online could address my node as an RPC server. An example would be like creating a node with infura where you can address that RPC URL from any client (except in this case, the "infura node" is self hosted in that example). As for the "why," I'm going to be testing a network with a few hundred users and testers across the globe who will need access to my ETH node. Hopefully that helps 

Comment: But what do you mean with "it's not visible to the public"? You tried accessing it with <IP>:8545 and it didn't work? In that case I'd check if that port is open, check the network connectivity, firewall, etc. Another check is enabling a higher verbosity in geth logs and examining the arriving requests.